# How to solve the coding error with python?

Tags: python

> Topic: Check adjacent odd numbers
> Problem description: Enter 5 numbers
>
> Input description: Whether the output has adjacent odd numbers.
>
> Output description: If there are adjacent odd numbers, output the first group of adjacent odd numbers, otherwise, turn out NO.
>
> ```
> Sample Input:   Sample Output:
> 5 6 7 8 9       NO⏎
> 8 9 11 13 15    9,11⏎
> ```
>
> Writing condition:
> Input: Use the list(), map(), int() functions to convert the input string to a sequence of integers
>
> Process: Use a loop to check for adjacent odd numbers
>
> Output: apply f-string

```py
num1, num2, num3, num4, num5 = map(int,input().split())
list1= [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5]
for i in range(list1[0], list1[4]):
  if i%2 != 0:
    for j in range(list1[1], list1[4]):
      if j%2 != 0 :
        break
    print(f'{i, j}')
  else :
    print('NO')
```

I used for-loop to write the code but the result is a wrong error. I excepted that when I input `5 6 7 8 9` and the actual result is `NO`. However, my wrong result is

```
(5, 7)
NO 
(7, 7)
NO
```

Comment: Should the loop be `for i in list1:`?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `range` you are creating an entirely new set of numbers. You need to use the `list` directly. An easy way to solve this problem is by using [zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) on the `list` and an offset of the `list`

This way you can compare the current number with the next number without creating more loops.

```
#you can apply your split results directly to the list
#no need to unpack and repack the data
data = list(map(int,input().split()))

for i,j in zip(data, data[1:]):

    #you don't need explicit equality (ie. i%2!=0)
    #both of these either "are" or "aren't"
    if i%2 and j%2:
        #the way you wrote your fstring 
        #you were actually printing a tuple
        print(f'{i}, {j}')
        break
else: 
    #if `break` was never reached
    print('NO')
```